# How can I echo a message and return a code to AJAX from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

All,

I have an AJAX function, that calls a PHP URL through html data type. I cannot use other datatypes for my AJAX requests due to server constraints. I am trying to print a message and also handle scenarios based on the return code. The following code doesn't seem to work. Can you advise?

Here's a simple AJAX call:

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "validateUser.php",
       dataType: html,
       success: function(msg, errorCode){
         if(errorCode == 10)
         {
           callAFunction();
         }
         else if(errorCode == 20)
         {
           callSomething();
         }
         else
         {
           doSomethingElse();
         }
       }
     });

PHP CODE:
---------
 <?php
       function validateUser()
        {
          $username = 'xyz';
          if (!empty($username) && strlen($username)>5)
           {
             echo 'User Validated';
             return 10;
           }
           else if (empty($username))
           {
             echo 'Improper Username';
             return 20;
           }
           else if (strlen($username)<5)
           {
             echo 'Username length should be atleast 5 characters';
             return 30;
           } 
          exit;
         }
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP is a just a function. It is not being called.

Also, you are not sending any data to your PHP file.

Comment: Well, it's supposed to just show the gist of what i am trying to do, not the entire code :)

Comment: I think the dataType is wrong too.

The value is supposed to be a string, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is print them in div something like this.

```
<div class="errorcode">30</div><div class="errormessage">Username length should be atleast 5 characters</div>
```

and then in your success function in ajax you can use jquery to parse the response text and use selectors like `$(".errorcode").html() and $(".errormessage").html()` and get the response. this makes things easy

also looks like you are not posting anything

Answer (score 0):

Remove `exit;` at the end of validateUser(). It causes the execution of the entire script to stop immediately.
Since this is the last line of validateUser(), there is no need to add `return`.

Documentation: [exit](http://php.net/exit), [return](http://php.net/return)